# Django model form applying user viewing data as the user from form

Tags: python, django, django-models, modelform

I have a model form which adds fields (email, latitude etc) and then my views.py attaches the user to the form before it saves. However, when I look at the data in the admin panel, it just assigns my username to all of the entries. If I log in as a different user, I get the same form entries but all with the new username attached.

**Views.py**

```
    form = SafezoneForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SafezoneForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            Safezone.userid = request.user #### gets username here and assigns to model
            instance.save()
            return redirect('loadingsafezone')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'V2maparonno_create_safe_zoneV2.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Safezone(models.Model):
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    useremail = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    latitudecentre = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longitudecentre = models.FloatField(null=True)
    latcorner1 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    latcorner2 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    latcorner3 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    latcorner4 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longcorner1 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longcorner2 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longcorner3 = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longcorner4 = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.longcorner1 = self.longitudecentre - 0.6
        self.longcorner2 = self.longitudecentre + 0.6
        self.longcorner3 = self.longitudecentre + 0.6
        self.longcorner4 = self.longitudecentre - 0.6

        self.latcorner1 = self.latitudecentre - 0.6
        self.latcorner2 = self.latitudecentre - 0.6
        self.latcorner3 = self.latitudecentre + 0.6
        self.latcorner4 = self.latitudecentre + 0.6

        super(Safezone, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userid or ''
```

Comment: The assignment `Safezone.userid = request.user` in your views.py looks like it should be `instance.userid = request.user`

Comment: thanks @elyas, you just solved it. Makes total sense in hindsight, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Changed to **instance.userid** instead of *safezone.userid* as @elyas suggested and this is now solved.